# why maximum number of corner points is m+nCn?

Tags: optimization, linear-programming

In Linear programming we have:

maximum number of corner points for a problem with m constrains and n variable is . n+mCn . (taking a combination of the number of equations plus variables with number of variables )

why this is the case? I have no idea why this is true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define:

```
m = number of rows = number of logical variables (slacks)
n = number of columns = number of structural variables
```

so the **total number of variables** is `n+m`

Further, we have:

```
number of basic variables = m (solved by linear algebra)
number of non-basic variables = n (temporarily fixed, usually at 0)
```

The total number of corner points is equal to the number of ways we can choose `m` basic variables out of `n+m` total variables.

But we have:

```
 n+m choose m  = n+m choose n
```

Note that in general many of these bases are infeasible.